# Frameset not displaying

Tags: html, frameset

I got this exercise I have to make involving framesets. I've created this html:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <frameset rows="50%,50%" cols="50%,50%">
        <frame src="../../topleft.html" name="topleft">
        <frame src="topright.html" name="topright">
        <frame src="botleft.html" name="botleft">
        <frameset rows="50%,50%">
            <frameset cols="50%,50%">
                <frame src="brtl.html" name="brtl">
                <frame src="brtr.html" name="brtr">
            </frameset>
            <frame src="botrbot.html" name="botrbot">
        </frameset>
    </frameset>

    </body>
    </html>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>topleft.html</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    topleft
    </body>
    </html>
```

All the other html's are identical to topleft.html and therefor I've not included them. Nothing is showing in my browser. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Google chrome. Arbitrary text to make the comment valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you are using `frameset` there is no use of body, so just remove the `<body>` and `</body>`.
if you want the browser to display something when no frames are supported follow this [link](http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/frames/noframes.html).

Answer (score 0):

`Frameset` tag can't use the body, so just remove tag after try comes to output.